# How to print the response from the web platform in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, url

In my code I have launched the URL on the web platform, getting a response also, I am unable to get and print the response from the web end.

This is my simple code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

class MyWebApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWebApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWebApp> createState() => _MyWebAppState();
}

class _MyWebAppState extends State<MyWebApp> {
  final url =
      "https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/initsso?idpid=C02qtgmcd&spid=859837136968&forceauthn=false";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Web Application"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed:
                  () {
                html.window.open(url, 'Google Authentication', 'popup');
              },
              child: const Text("Login")),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the response I am getting on the web end, but unable to get it:

```
{"status":1,"msg":"user Authenticated !!","user":{"userFirstName":"Max","userLastName":"Well","userEmail":"max@thexyz.in","userType":"manager","manager":true,"employee":false,"teamLead":false},"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImdhdXJhdkB0aGVsYXR0aWNlLmluIiwiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiR2F1cmF2IiwibGFzdE5hbWUiOiJLdW1hciIsIm1hbmFnZXIiOnRydWUsImVtcGxveWVlIjpmYWxzZSwidGVhbUxlYWQiOmZhbHNlLCJpYXQiOjE3MDAyMDQ4NjQsImV4cCI6MTcwMDI5MTI2NH0.alsdjflaksjweio39lskdjf923030923jslkdf"}
```

Can anyone please help me to get and print the response in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Try using listner for listen to messages send from the opened window using `html.window.onMessage.listen`. When a message is received, it's parsed as JSON and printed to the console. You can then manipulate or use the received data as needed within your Flutter application.

Remember that this assumes the opened window sends a message with the response JSON. You might need to adjust this code based on how the response is sent from the opened URL.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

class MyWebApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWebApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWebApp> createState() => _MyWebAppState();
}

class _MyWebAppState extends State<MyWebApp> {
  final url = "your url";
      

  void _openUrl() {
    html.window.open(url, 'Google Authentication', 'popup');
    html.window.onMessage.listen((event) {
      final receivedData = json.decode(event.data);
      print(receivedData); // Print the received data in the console
      // Handle the received data as needed
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Web Application"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _openUrl,
            child: const Text("Login"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Alternatively solution,

To capture the response data from the opened URL, you can use `Window.postMessage` in JavaScript within the opened window and listen for this message in your Flutter app.

First you should make a `webviewcontroller` like bellow,

```
late WebViewController _webViewController;
```

Full implementation,

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class MyWebApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWebApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWebApp> createState() => _MyWebAppState();
}

class _MyWebAppState extends State<MyWebApp> {
  final url =
      "https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/initsso?idpid=C02qtgmcd&spid=859837136968&forceauthn=false";

  late WebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Web Application"),
      ),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: url,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
          _webViewController = controller;
        },
        javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
          JavascriptChannel(
            name: 'PrintResponse',
            onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
              final receivedData = json.decode(message.message);
              print(receivedData); // Print the received data in the console
              // Handle the received data as needed
            },
          ),
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          if (_webViewController != null) {
            await _webViewController.evaluateJavascript(
                'window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(document.body.innerText))');
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.send),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This updated code utilizes `WebView` from `webview_flutter` to load the URL within your Flutter app. It sets up a JavascriptChannel to receive messages from the web content. When the floating action button is pressed, it evaluates JavaScript to send the content of the web page via `window.postMessage`.

Comment: Hi @Dhanusha, I have tried using `html.window.onMessage.listen((event)`, Still, I don't see any response in the console. Do we have any alternate solution?

Comment: Nothing is impossible we will try

Comment: What did u got your debug

Comment: this is what I got:

Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52897/a5DC1IYy-hc=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52897/a5DC1IYy-hc=/ws
The webOnlyAssetManager getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `assetManager` from `dart:ui_web` instead.
The webOnlyAssetManager getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `assetManager` from `dart:ui_web` instead.

Comment: I updated new solution as alternative refer it, if you update your code and then plz pub clean and upgrade before run your project.

Comment: Will the `webView` be supported on the web platform?